# Geoalchemy2 Find a location within certain distance within given coordinate

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, geolocation, geoalchemy2

I have a flask app that first fetches a location from Google Maps API and am trying to find the location that is closer to it within 1500 meters that is in the database I have.

Here is my places model.

```
class Places(db.Model):
    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),
                     primary_key=True,
                     server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    # For Near Location Querying
    geometric_point = db.Column(
        Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326), nullable=False)
```

I have this query to find the entry that has location nearby the submitted `lng` and `lat` within 1500meters.

```
def get_nearby_aqi_node(lat, lng):
    distance_in_meters = 1500

    geo_wkb = func.Geometry(func.ST_GeographyFromText(
        'POINT({} {})'.format(lng, lat)))

    point = db.session.query(Places.name,
                                Places.uuid).\
        filter(func.ST_DFullyWithin(Places.geometric_point, geo_wkb, distance_in_meters)).\
        order_by(
        Comparator.distance_centroid(Places.geometric_point, geo_wkb)).limit(1).first()

    return point
```

I am getting the single point that is closer to the place but it is not within the 1500 meter restriction. 
I get the same result with the `.filter()` removed.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this filter for distances in meters? Thanks.

Comment: I recall fixing this at least to what i could at the time. I have made the project open source, you can check if the code i wrote there works or not. 

https://github.com/abhijithvijayan/OpenAir/blob/bb48ebe441caa6532fc97ab2369cfdfd61271e6d/server/app/models/Place.py#L45

some logic I wrote for collecting all the points nearby

https://github.com/abhijithvijayan/OpenAir/blob/bb48ebe441caa6532fc97ab2369cfdfd61271e6d/server/app/api/aqi.py#L92

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your points are of the `geometry` type with an CRS `4326`, whose unit is degrees. The filer is a distance constraint of 1500 degrees (which is meaningless).

Even though you have called once `func.ST_GeographyFromText()`, the output is still a `geometry` and the cast between the two is automatic.

You can use the `geography` type for both points in order to use a distance in meters.

Comment: So, should I change the column to use
`location = geoalchemy.GeometryColumn(Geography(2), comparator=PGComparator)`

instead  or convert the `distance in meters` to `degree radius`?

Comment: Don't measure distances in degrees, it is plain wrong. A degree of longitude is not the same length as a degree of latitude